# C language: Difference between two ways of pointer assignment

Tags: c, pointers

```
int a[10];
int *p = a; //way 1
int *p1 = &a[0]; //way 2
```

Could you tell me the differences between two ways above?

Comment: The first way, way 1, is _slightly_ wrong: you are assigning an "int array" to an "int pointer". Yet it works, because the final result is the same - the address of a and a[0] are the same. But the second form is _slightly_ more correct. (This is kind of philosophy, anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Both assign the address of the first element to the pointer `p` and `p1` respectively.

In the first case, `a` is automatically converted to the address of the first element. In the second case it uses the address of the first element explicitly.

Comment: The first method does not take the address of the array, and the address of the array is not equivalent to the address of the first element. The first method uses the expression `a`. In this, the identifier `a` stands for the array. In this expression, but not all expressions, the array is **automatically converted** to the address of its first element. This conversion does not happen when an array is the operand of `sizeof`, unary `&`, or `_Alignof` or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Comment: To see that the address of the array is not equivalent to the address of its first element, consider that `int *p = &a;` would produce a warning message due to mismatched types, and `&a+1` points to a different location (beyond the array) than `&a[0]+1` (the second element of the array).